# share on facebook photo api new IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

I found this tutorial to share photos on the facebook wall is perfect however if I change the ID of the facebook api, putting my ID instead of using the MyGrades it does not work, because the Facebook SDK has been updated and is no longer compatible.

I get the following message: "Sorry, the application you are using is Facebook integration is misconfigured ......"

've researched about the solution would be to update the facebook api.

anyone have a suggestion that works exactly like this example but with the current api?

http://www.crocko.com/D880103DB52C4426B1D7331A69CADDE4/FacebookPostTutorial.zip

Answer (score 0):

With ios6, apple as introduced a number of their own sharing tools in the Social framework. I'd suggest that you look into SLComposeViewController. There is a good explanation of it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing)