# iOS6 facebook integration (image post)

Tags: iphone, facebook, image

I just want to add facebook functionality in my app. i want to add image on facebook through my app.

Is there any sample available for iOS6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial for SLComposeViewController sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visit this official documentation, *[SLComposeViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)*.

Apple has created a social framework. `SLComposeViewController` is the controller which will handle all the request for social interaction.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewController *objSLComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        [objSLComposeViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        switch(result)
        {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
        }
    }
    [objSLComposeViewController addImage:yourImage];
    [objSLComposeViewController setInitialText:@"YourInitialText"];
    [objSLComposeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YourURL"]];
    [objSLComposeViewController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentModalviewController:objSLComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot jennis, Its perfect for iOS6. 

but what about for iOS5?

Comment: For iOS5 you need to integrate older SDK of facebook. Post other question will also guide in that.