# Facebook SLComposeViewController URL shows up in body if both URL and image present

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

Using `SLComposeViewController`, I notice curious behavior when posting to Facebook if both the image and the URL are present. Specifically, if you have both image and URL, the URL appears in the body of the Facebook post in the view of the `SLComposeViewController`, immediately after the `initialText` if I do the following:

```
SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

NSString *text = @"This is a test Facebook post with SLComposeViewController.";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing"];
UIImage *image = ...;

[controller setInitialText:text];
[controller addURL:url];
[controller addImage:image];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That's obviously a hassle because the if the URL is long, the initial text is pushed off of the visible portion of the view of `SLComposeViewController` and I only see the latter portion of the URL:

[image]

If I repeat this process, this time not adding the image to the post, the text of the URL conveniently does not show up in the body at all (even though it shows up properly online).

[image]

Bottom line, only if there is an image *and* and URL does the URL show up in the body of the post. And I see this same pattern when I use `FBNativeDialogs`.

Is there any way to stop that behavior with `SLComposeViewController`, so that I can have both image and URL connected to the Facebook post without exposing the user to the web site's long, ugly URL? Clearly I can use any of the non-`SLComposeViewController` solutions (e.g. design my own UI for composing the Facebook post, using Facebook's deprecated [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/), etc.). Just wondering if I'm overlooking some obvious `SLComposeViewController` solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end, I've given up on the `SLComposeViewController` (as well as the `FBNativeDialogs`). They present a nice, integrated feel, but given that my posts invariably include both photo and URL, this really doesn't work. On top of that, the posts were not correctly attributed as being from my app.

So, in the end, I've written my own user interface and use the the Facebook SDK 3.1 `FBRequestConnection` as outlined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/). I think it's a little silly that we all have to make our own UI because the weaknesses in the native UI, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 6):

The new dialog seems to be designed around you providing most of the share data as  tags on the website the provided link points to. Like this:

Title:

```
<title>TITLE</title>
```

Description:

```
<meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">
```

Image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE_URL">
```

App ID:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
```

This way you only need to provide the initial text and an URL. You can look how the official Youtube app does it's Facebook sharing for an example.

Comment: it doesn't work and Ytbe too! look carefully question

Answer (score -5):

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *format = @"“%@” %@ /via @DesignSceneApp";
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, title, url]
NSUInteger idx = title.length;
while (![twitter setInitialText:message]) {
    idx -= 5;
    if (idx > 5) {
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:format,
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@…", [title substringToIndex:idx]],
            url
        ];
    } else {
        // Give up on the title.
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ /via @DesignSceneApp", url];
        [twitter setInitialText:message];
        break;
    }
}

[self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: still no progress in code formatting? -1 as an incentive to read the help :-)

Comment: @Tamilarasan, I don't see how this code solves the specific problem that only manifests itself when sending both URL and and picture in single Facebook post. You're neither using Facebook nor sending a picture. Looks like you're trying to iteratively solve the "length of Tweet" problem, but that's not the issue here. Thank you for your time, though.

Comment: Format your code please, and, read the question before COPY & PASTE.