# Am I adding URL correctly to SLComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

```
-(void) vPostStuffs:(UIViewController *) parent withImage:(UIImage *) image andText:(NSString *) text andURL: (NSString *) URL
{
    // Create a compose view controller for the service type Twitter
    SLComposeViewController *mulitpartPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:self.strSLServiceType];

    if (text)
    {
        [mulitpartPost setInitialText:text];
    }

    if (URL)
    {
        [mulitpartPost addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    }

    if (image)
    {
        [mulitpartPost addImage:image];
    }

    [parent presentViewController:mulitpartPost animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In Android, facebook will display a screen shot of URL instead of simply writing the URL in the post. In my iOS application, facebook simply display the URL

What am I missing?

Is this related to [Facebook SLComposeViewController URL shows up in body if both URL and image present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867135/facebook-slcomposeviewcontroller-url-shows-up-in-body-if-both-url-and-image-pres)

Here is the thing. If I do not display the image, if I get rid [mulitpartPost addImage:image]; then the URL doesn't show up as anything.

In twitter, URL and pictures do not show up. Even though after pressing post it does shows up on the twitter.

In facebook, URL screenshot never shows up no matter what even though it shows up after posting.

In twitter, those with multiple twitter accounts will have twitter post to the wrong account.