# Is there an open source framework to easily implement social sharing with SLComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, social-networking, sharing

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing) on SO where someone gave a quick tutorial for how to use SLComposeViewController directly.

Everyone wants to implement sharing features in their apps and I can imagine there is a framework which already implemented a configurable share sheet that offers the user a lot of different options?

I can't imagine everyone is reinventing this wheel all the time. But I wasn't lucky finding an alternative to doing it myself either.

All I need is an overlay or action sheet which pops up with various share options. Then the user taps one, and the appropriate SLComposeViewController (or similar) will be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check share kit which is an opensource framework: http://getsharekit.com or addthis which is not open but gives you the desired result http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide

Comment: ShareKit does not use SLComposeViewController

Comment: If the user has a Twitter account on the iPhone, would ShareKit be intelligent enough about using this account or does it prompt the user to enter username + password, as opposed to SLComposeViewController?