# How to Show Tweet via [MyAppName] in Twitter when I tweet via SLComposeViewController iOS sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have implemented to  tweet by default ios sdk using SLComposeViewController ,

But In twitter , Its Shows via iOS by default, 
How I can set my Appname, that it will show "via [MyAppName]" in twitter

I have already create app with same name of ios app in twitter and its only 5 character name,
My App is live on app store. Still It doesn't show via[My App name]

Please give feedback of any other suggestion or any idea you have.

Comment: do check the following ,might it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that using SLComposeViewController.

You'll need to have registered an "application" (AKA obtain an API key) on dev.twitter.com to use custom name in "via [MyAppName]" on Twitter.

After that, you can create your own custom view to post to Twitter.