# is it possible to (Rate /review) FB page from native ios application?

Tags: ios, facebook, rate

i want to allow a user to login using facebook id and give rating to the particular FB page . is it possible from native ios application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create a Rating via the Graph API. Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/ratings

You can only read Ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **SocialFramework**, and sharing data on facebook, but not give raiting. More information:
[tutorial for SLCompose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing)