# How to share both Image and Text together in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share both image and text in swift. but when i choose to share via facebook, messenger or whatsapp it only gives text (image is not shared). I am using UIActivityViewController for sharing.

here is my code:

```
func displayShareSheet(latitude:NSString?, longitude:NSString?, image:UIImage?, address:NSString? ) {
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [(latitude as NSString?)!, (longitude as NSString?)!, (image as UIImage?)!, (address as NSString?)!], applicationActivities: nil)
    presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {}
)
}
```

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931946/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: this will share either image or text. i want both the things to be shared. @Sanjeetverma

Comment: see my answer below!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is `UIActivityViewController` code is working for me. also attached screen shot for both the methods.

```
 func shareImage() {
            let img = UIImage(named: "SoSampleImage")
            let messageStr = "Ketan SO"
            let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [img!, messageStr], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Screen shot for UIActivityViewController example :

[image]

**Alternative Using SLComposeViewController :**

```
func share(){
        let img = UIImage(named: "SoSampleImage")
        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        composeSheet.setInitialText("Hello, Ketan!")
        composeSheet.addImage(img)
        self.presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Screen shot for SLComposeViewController example :

[image]

Hope it will help you..

Do let me know if you have any query.

Comment: does this works for only facebook ? or everything @Ketan P

Comment: @hussain your question is for FB so I prepare code for FB only... But I think it should work for all option which support both image & text sharing together...

Comment: @hussain If helps you. pl. make it as answer. It will help other SO user to resolve same kind if issue.

Comment: @hussain thanks for the reply you may forget to make it answer. Note : It will help other SO user to resolve same kind if issue.

Comment: what is SLComposeViewController??

Comment: Please refer : https://developer.apple.com/reference/social/slcomposeviewcontroller      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503287/tutorial-for-slcomposeviewcontroller-sharing   Do let me know if you require any other information.

Comment: either of it was not working for you ? can you share your code ? what error you get ?

Comment: let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (activityItems: [latitude!,longitude!,image!,address!, ourURL], applicationActivities: nil)
            
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]
            self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: "SoSampleImage1")
let latitude = 23.23232412
let longitude = 46.23232412
let address = "Address"
let ourURL = "our  URL"
let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController (activityItems: [latitude,longitude,image!,address, ourURL], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) I use this rather lat and long everything else I am able to see.

Comment: Same code is working for me.. Thats why attach screen shot as well.

Comment: This won't share the text when shared to Facebook Messenger. How do you do that?

Comment: @AndiAna may be SDK is changed now. need to check for the same.

Comment: This method won't work when you try to send both text and image together to whatsapp.
Refer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670873

Answer (score 0):

Try this This is working for me!!!

```
@IBAction func btnExport(sender: AnyObject)
{

    print("Export")
    let someText:String = "Hello want to share text also"
    let objectsToShare:UIImage = self.imgView.image!
    let sharedObjects:[AnyObject] = [objectsToShare,someText]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems : sharedObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: it is not working for facebook, whatsapp aan messenger.
if u want to send mail or text this works.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this with the help of `VisualActivityViewController` which is present in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/naturaln0va/VisualActivityViewController)

It gives me a nice, custom view as well--one that shows the user both the text and image that the user is going to share.