# Sharing to Instagram using UIActivityView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, instagram, social-media

Im trying to share a Instagram post from an app that I made in swiftUI using UIActivityView, but whenever I try to share it only the picture shows up and the caption doesn't. The same thing happens with Facebook.

```
func sharePost(){
        isSheetShowing.toggle()
        let caption = "Hello, world!"

        if let image = UIImage(named: "Image") {

            let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image,caption], applicationActivities: nil)

            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(vc,animated : true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't pass a text to Instagram. Maybe try only passing an image. Let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

UIActivityController needs to correctly recognize what exactly you are trying to share in order to display it corrrectly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632365/how-to-share-both-image-and-text-together-in-swift) solution seems to answer your question directly.

Also, this is kind of an anti-pattern in SwiftUI (presenting it directly on the window). You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533564/showing-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-switui) question out.